# Dependence rank: what is the size of the largest subcollection of random variables which is statistically independent?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_p$ be random variables on the same space. Define their dependence rank, denoted $rank(X_1,\ldots,X_p)$ as the largest nonnegative integer $k$ such that there is a subcollection of $k$ out of the $p$ random variables which are mutually independent (i.e theire joint distribution funciton factors as a product of their individual distribution funcitons). Of course, every singleton $\{X_i\}$ forms an independent collection. Thus $1 \le rank(X_1,\ldots,X_p) \le p$, and the upper bound is attained if $X_1,\ldots,X_p$ are independent to begin with.

**Question.** Is the above notion of rank defined above studied in the literature ? Are there any interesting properties of quantity ? Are the any known proxies for this concept ?

Comment: I don't think you can say much from the covariance matrix.  Consider a) $X$ and $Y$ independent uniform variables on $[-1,1]$, or b) $X$ as before, $Y = 2|X|$. They have the same covariance matrix but a) has rank 2 and b) has rank 1.

Comment: Yes, indeed covarance matrices don't capture nonlinear dependence patterns. Removed my comment above cov matrix.

Comment: Recall that for $k\ge 3$, [pairwise independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence) is weaker than full ("mutual") independence. What is your motivation for using "pairwise" in your definition?

Comment: It was a problem with terminology. Removed the "pairwise" adjective.